# User-Id for Push-Notification on Actions for Google

Tags: push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-api-java-client

I try to make a push notification for my google assistant app.
I used the sendNotification Code form the google developer site: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

I am coding Java.
Everything is working, expect getting the correct user id.
When I hardcode my user it works, but how do I get the user id in the code?

I tried following code:

```
Argument arg_userId = request.getArgument(ConstantsKt.ARG_UPDATES_USER_ID);
```

String userId = request.getUser().getUserId();

--> I get "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

```
String userId = arg_userId.getRawText();
```

--> same Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the approach you're taking to get the notification ID:

1. The ID attached to the user object is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) and probably unavailable.
2. This wasn't the ID you wanted anyway.

In the response where the user [finalizes the notification](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#finalize_the_subscription), that response includes an ID which you should get and store. Since you're using Java, the code might look something like this:

```
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = getResponseBuilder(request);

Argument permission = request.getArgument(ConstantsKt.ARG_PERMISSION);
if (permission != null) {
  Argument userId = request.getArgument(ConstantsKt.ARG_UPDATES_USER_ID);
  // code to save intent and userID in your db
  responseBuilder.add("Ok, I'll start alerting you.").endConversation();
} else {
  responseBuilder.add("Ok, I won't alert you.");
}
return responseBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Okay, I don't know how I could missed that... Thanks for That, it works now!

Comment: It is easy to miss